# How can I use an array formula with this reverse geocode script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

Here is the Google Script:

```
function reverse_geocode(lat,lng) {
Utilities.sleep(1500);

var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(lat,lng);
for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
var result = response.results[i];
Logger.log('%s: %s, %s', result.formatted_address, result.geometry.location.lat,
result.geometry.location.lng);
return result.formatted_address;
}
}
```

[image]

I'm trying to take coordinates from columns A and B and have them convert to an address after they appear in the sheet. I'd like to use an array here so the rows won't be used until they actually contain data. I followed this tutorial for the script: https://blogs.oregonstate.edu/deanna/2020/08/01/reverse-geocode-google-sheet/

Any ideas? Hope you can help.

Edit: the formula should be something more along the lines of:

```
=ArrayFormula(reverse_geocode(A1:A,B1:B))
```

Comment: Have you  tried anything to convert the script to support arrays?

Comment: good idea. terrible with google scripts but i'll try now.

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: not having much luck with this. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have altered your script to be able to accept and use an array.

```js
/**
 * Returns addresses from given coordinates
 *
 * @param {array} input The range containing the data.
 * @return The coordinates as addresses.
 * @customfunction
 */

function reverse_geocode(range) {
var arr = [];
for(var i of range) {
  let lat = i[0];
  let lng = i[1];
  var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(lat,lng);
  var result = response.results[0];
  Logger.log('%s: %s, %s', result.formatted_address, result.geometry.location.lat,
  result.geometry.location.lng);
  arr.push(result.formatted_address);
}
return arr;
}
```

This script will read and process each row within the given range individually, insert the results into an array, and lastly output the results.

If you have difficulty with this, have any questions, or would like this script altered in any way, please let me know

Hope this helps!

---

### Edit

The script above is not the original, please see edit history for the first version.

Below is the response I get when using the (new) above script:

[image: ex]

This script successfully returns the closest addresses for a given range.

Comment: hrmm =reverse_geocode(A:B), tried several variations. =reverse_geocode(A3:B3), =reverse_geocode(A3:A,B3:B). doesn't seem to work

Comment: interesting.. this is pushing out so many more addresses than asked for though. how odd!! :O

Comment: =reverse_geocode(A3:B3) results in 11 rows being filled with similar location information.. all from a single set of coordinates

Comment: not exactly the desired output. everything beyond row 2 is undesirable information. row 3 should contain a new set of coordinates for another address to be generated

Comment: @nty51 please see most recent edit, I think this achieves what you are looking for

Comment: the only issue now is it is no longer an array. the first set of coordinates converts to an address, and anything below those coordinates does nothing. even when placed into an array like so: =ArrayFormula(reverse_geocode(A3:B3))

Comment: @nty51 correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems you are only looking at one row of data with that formula (`A3:B3`). Try changing it to something like `=reverse_geocode(A3:B5)`, where more than one row is called

Comment: That did the trick! you are brilliant! thank you so much!